# Input type file triggering twice in mozilla(windows)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload, html-input

I have a strange issue with my website(using **backbone.js**,but i don't feel its something related to this framework). The template i am using is a **bootstrap** powered Admin theme called *Ace Admin*.

The **HTML** for file is as follows :

```
<input type="file" class="profileImage" name="profileImage" id="id-input-file-1" />
```

The **Script** associated for the same :

```
    $('#id-input-file-1').ace_file_input({
        no_file:'Image resolution 640*640',
        btn_choose:'Choose',
        btn_change:'Change',
        droppable:false,
        onchange:null,
        thumbnail:true,
        whitelist:'gif|png|jpg|jpeg',
        blacklist:'exe|php',
        //onchange:''
        //
    });
```

In **mozilla** alone, that too in **windows machine**, when i click on the `input` the file selection screen appears twice. To be precise, when i click the input the local drive window opens up. I select a file and close it. As soon as i close it another window opens up. In effect i have to close two windows one after another if i click on file input.

So my question is :

1. What am i doing wrong here?
2. Can i handle this in someway? Like say i get the click event and register the status and handle the second call by checking with status or so?
3. Is there a more obvious way of handling this through scripting?

**My Input file** :

[image]

**The pop-up** :

[image]

Comment: Hey Do you know how to show stored image in this ace admin file field? In edit form i want to show the stored image with remove link

Comment: Hi @SatheeshNarayanan : Yes you can show the stored image with remove link. The remove link part will come if you add one class to the input field/span. The image for edit part, u have to display as a small thumbnail which you would need some customization. After this, add a class for the remove icon and then `onclick` of that, just empty out the `img src` and the link in `<input>`. Hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have implemented this and it's working fine. Thanks again

Comment: @RoyMJ : Hello Roy, How did you specified the path(server side script to upload the image)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 1 long month, i found the solution. There was a min file with the template and inside that there was a code as follows specially for mozilla :

```
        if (b.browser.mozilla) {
            n.on("click", function () {
                if (!k.disabled && !m.attr("readonly")) {
                    m.click()
                }
            })
        }
```

When i removed this, it no longer triggers the file upload twice. I guess this was used for older versions of mozilla. There was lots of styles related to a single file button and the original file type was hidden from view.